# Bootstrap 4 modal close and redirect url in new tab

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a bootstrap modal when the site loads and close it after 3 seconds, and when it closes it redirects to a new URL in a new tab.
this is code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <div class="model-box">
             <div class="row">
                 <img src="img/mod/pop-header.svg" alt="" class="model-img1">
             </div>          
             <a href="#" class="model-btn" target="_blank">Get Your 100% Bounus</a>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
// Open modal on page load
$("#myModal1").modal('show');
//redirect after 5seconds
setInterval(function(){
   $("#myModal").modal('hide');
  window.open('http://127.0.0.1:30008/','_blank');},3000);
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('#myModal1').modal('hide')
}, 3000);

})
  </script>
```

currently i use this code but it redirects  after 3 scound continuously but i want to redirect only once when the modal is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using setInterval which would run every time interval, for one-time occurrence you should use setTimeout, which would run once after the specified time

Try Below Snippet

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <div class="model-box">
             <div class="row">
                 <img src="img/mod/pop-header.svg" alt="" class="model-img1">
             </div>          
             <a href="#" class="model-btn" target="_blank">Get Your 100% Bounus</a>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
// Open modal on page load
$("#myModal1").modal('show');
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
   window.open('http://127.0.0.1:30008/','_blank'); // Added redirect in setTime out and removed the setInterval, which would run on each time after the specified duration.
}, 3000);

})
  </script>
```